# How to append multiple dictionary value containing in a nested list

Tags: python-3.x, data-structures

I am trying to append multiple dictionary value containing in a nested list as below but not getting the expected output.

```
lst = [[{'A': 'abc1'}], [{'A': 'xyz'}, {'2 ': '123'}], [{'A': 'abc2'}, {'B': 'abc14'}], [{'X': 'abc3'}, {'B': 'abc4'}, {'4': 'abc10'}, {'': '123dfghfh'}]]

import pandas as pd
result = []

for wrd in lst:
    for dct in wrd:
        vl_check = [val for val in dct.values() if 'abc' in val]
        result.append(','.join(vl_check) if vl_check else 'NA')

data = {'Result': result}
final_result = pd.DataFrame(dict([(k,pd.Series(v)) for k,v in data.items()]))
```

Expected output should like below:

```
  final_result
0 abc1
1 NA
2 abc2, abc14
3 abc3, abc4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a great attempt, you came pretty close. The problem happens here:

```
    for dct in wrd: 
        vl_check = [val for val in dct.values() if 'abc' in val]
        result.append(','.join(vl_check) if vl_check else 'NA')  # << Problem!!
```

You're adding one row to the result for each `dct` in each `wrd`. You want all elements of a single `wrd` to be in the same row. Additionally, if none of the elements in `wrd` have an `'abc'`, then you could end up with multiple NAs. Here's my suggestion:

```
for wrd in lst:
    vl_check = []
    for dct in wrd:
        vl_check += [val for val in dct.values() if 'abc' in val]
    result.append(','.join(vl_check) if vl_check else 'NA')
```

First, we append to the same `vl_check` for all items in a single `wrd`. When we're done, we `str.join()` that list, so that all these items are in a single string that we put in `result`.

The code above gives the output:

```
            Result
0             abc1
1               NA
2       abc2,abc14
3  abc3,abc4,abc10
```